# Iterate "Win32_Processor" to find multiple processors? Does it work that way?

Tags: c#, wmi

When i have the following:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");
ManagementObjectCollection myobject = searcher.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject item in myobject)
        {
           //Name
           Console.WriteLine(item["Name"].ToString());
        }
```

Is this going through each Physical Processor and obtaining the Name for that particular processor?  I haven't seen an instance were the `foreach()` iterates move than once... I've worked with `Win32_Processor`, `Win32_BIOS`, `Win32_ComputerSystem`, so on..

In this case, if the server has more than 1 physical processor, would this `for-each` have more than one iteration? How does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true, by using the query:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor
```

there is an iteration per physical processor. You might be interested to take a look at the `DeviceId`, `SocketDesignation` and `NumberOfCores` properties.

Comment: Thank you, I noticed it does iterate on "Win32_PhysicalMemory" so i figured it would work the same for "Win32_Processors", but thank you for reassuring me.